# Best way to get user to input items of different types into a list

Tags: python, list, user-input

What's the best way in Python to prompt a user to input items to an empty list and ensure the entries are evaluated to correct data types?

For example user enters following mix of `int`, `float`, `str` and `list` item values:

```
24
190.45
'steve'
'steve smith'
['4A', '7B']
```

`new_list` becomes `[24, 190.45, 'steve', 'steve smith', ['4A', '7B']]`

I have tried two methods, each with significant issues.

**Method 1** - asking user to input space delimited line of list items, using `eval()` to evaluate and store data types correctly, and using `str.split()` to split string into component items using `' '` as delimiter:

```
#  user enters values separated by spaces
input_list = [eval(l) for l in(raw_input('Enter the items for your list separated by spaces: ').split())]
#  check by printing individual items with data type and also complete list
for item in input_list:
    print item, type(item)
print input_list
```

However, I understand using `eval()` is not good from a security perspective.  Also using `' '` delimiter for the split means I can't enter a string item like `'steve smith'`. However, I don't want to ask the user to input something ugly like comma delimiters, etc..

**Method 2** - using a `while` loop with `break`, asking the user to input each list item:

```
input_list = []
while True:
    item = eval(raw_input('Enter new list item (or <Enter> to quit): '))
    if item:
        input_list.append(item)
    else:
        break
```

Again, this uses `eval()` which I believe should be avoided.  Also hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> to break throws an EOF parsing error, I'm guessing because `eval()` can't evaluate it.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Using `eval()` is unsafe and generally a really bad idea for a number of reasons. Your best option is to accept all the input as strings, and then have ways of recognising what each type is, and from that, construct the right thing, and then put it into the appropriate structure. E.g: Try and call `int()` on it, if it doesn't work, it's not a integer, if it does, it is and you can put it in the right place.

Comment: do you want the items sorted by type or just cast to the correct type?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham just cast to correct type, though sorting by type is something I could look into as being a newbie I'm looking for practise, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method two is clearly superior, but needs a slight tweak to avoid the error you're seeing:

```
from ast import literal_eval

def get_input_list():
    input_list = []
    while True:
        item = raw_input('Enter new list item (or <Enter> to quit): ')
        if not item:
            break
        input_list.append(literal_eval(item))
    return input_list
```

Note the fact that the input is *only evaluated once it's known to be non-empty*, and the use of [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), which is safer than `eval`, although more limited:

> The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and `None`.

In use:

```
>>> get_input_list()
Enter new list item (or <Enter> to quit): 24
Enter new list item (or <Enter> to quit): 190.45
Enter new list item (or <Enter> to quit): 'steve'
Enter new list item (or <Enter> to quit): 
[24, 190.45, 'steve']
```

You could also add error handling, in case the user inputs a malformed string or something that can't be evaluated (e.g. `'foo` or `bar`):

```
try:
    input_list.append(literal_eval(item))
except (SyntaxError, ValueError):
    print "Input not understood. Please try again."
```

Comment: @johnrsharpe, thanks for response, very enlightening, will work through your suggestion and broaden my understanding, cheers